# jQuery Form Validation / Change validation type based on other form value

Tags: jquery, validation

We have a form that has a text input box it.  The data entered into this field generally has no validation (other than being required), but we want it to validate to date if another form equals a certain value.  Think about setting up password hints... You choose a hint type, say your dogs name which has no real validation, or you choose your birthday for a hint type in which case we want the field to have date validation...

$(#HNT_1) is 5 for birthday hint type... Now I just want to change the field #HNT_1_TE to go from free-form text to date validation...

I am using the form validation plugin...

Edit: I fixed it... 
I added an onchange handle to the select box that controlled the hint type, I checked if it's selected value was 5, if so I used the 'rule add' functionality of the validation module to add a date:true rule, if it wasn't, I used rule date:false.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your syntax here especially with the && at the end of your condition statement.  Have you tried to put your validating condition in a function and returning a pass/fail Boolean?  It appears you might have a false positive here.

Comment: @gurun8, my code and pretty much be ignored...  What I'm trying to say is, if the #HTN_1 field is not = 5 do nothing, or if it is 5 then this must also be true (where this is changing the validation to date)...

Comment: Have you tried to update the "required" option (e.g. true or false) using the API upon jQuery change events for these other fields?  Essentially you'd add an .change() event handler to the HNT_1 input and then toggle the "required" option for HNT_1_TE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an onchange handle to the select box that controlled the hint type, I checked if it's selected value was 5, if so I used the 'rule add' functionality of the validation module to add a date:true rule, if it wasn't, I used rule date:false.

Comment: Did this work?  This is pretty much what I was eluding to in my comment above but in a more jQuery route.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a different approach than your method, but you should check out the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

I've used it in the past to do exactly what you're describing (in my case, I had a set of text fields that were related to some radio buttons; choosing any one radio button activated its corresponding text field's validation settings).

Comment: I see - my particular example checks whether something is required, not whether it is a particular type (such as a date).  Sorry.